# After upgrading from Windows 10 to 11, why can’t I connect to the PC using SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, network-adapter, windows-11-upgrade

I can't get incoming SSH connections to work after upgrading from Windows 10 to 11.

Background:

- I was running Windows 10 on a PC, and I set up OpenSSH and keys to be able to remote into it. It had been working fine for years. The motherboard was incompatible with Windows 11 so I never upgraded.
- I recently built a new PC with almost all new hardware (new motherboard, drives, etc). Cloned my existing drive to one of the new hard drives. It worked fine. The new hardware is compatible with Windows 11, so I upgraded. After a few tweaks and a few reinstalls, almost everything is working fine. But incoming SSH connections are not working to the computer and I can't figure it out.

Things possibly helpful to know:

- Internet access is working fine, ethernet has static IP.
- *Cannot* ping local IP address from inside network.

  - Tried changing the static IP to something I've never used before, still won't ping.
- Outgoing SSH connections work fine.

  - Incoming fails.
- Outgoing RDP works fine.

  - Incoming fails.
- Outgoing access of networked folders works fine.

  - Incoming fails.

Things I want to avoid:

- Complete reinstall of Windows 11. I have many setups that would be a nightmare to redo.

Is it possible to do a total reset of the network adapters without resetting everything?

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling/reinstalling OpenSSH Client and Server in Optional Features.
- Ensuring port 22 is open in firewall.
- Rechecking permissions on administrators_authorized_keys.
- Temporarily disabling antivirus.

I am expecting SSH connections to and from PC to work properly. But only outgoing connections are working. Incoming are blocked, and trying to ping the IP fails.

---

Contents of `sshd_config`:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

---

Results of `netstat -an | sls ':22'`:

```
PowerShell 7.4.1
PS C:\Users\xxxx> netstat -an | sls ':22'

  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2266         127.0.0.1:6850         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2267         127.0.0.1:2268         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2268         127.0.0.1:2267         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6850         127.0.0.1:2266         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:22112        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.0.24:2258      104.17.107.108:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:22                [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when trying to connect? And can you add the contents of `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` to your post? Make sure the sshd service is running and listening with (powershell) `netstat -an | sls ':22 '`

Comment: Try to temporarily totally disable the firewall and any security software that you have in addition to Defender. Questions: Is the driver of the network adapter fully updated? Do you have any internal firewall on the router? Is the new computer getting the same internal IP address as the old one?

Comment: Thank you for these comments! I've added the content requested by Cpt Whale to original post.

When updating driver of the ethernet adapter, it says "The best drivers for your device are already installed." I don't have an internal firewall on the router. I didn't make any changes to the router since it had been working. I tried using the same IP address as the old comp, as well as a different static IP that I hadn't used on any other device ever. Neither is working.

I will try disabling every possible security software when I have more time to troubleshoot. But it's the same as before.

Comment: Provide the verbose logs for the client and the server at the time the client is connecting, likewise, we also need ACL for the private key on the server and the public key for the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a dope. My network was switched from Private to Public. Public had an override setting that blocked all incoming connections, even when they were allowed in firewall and elsewhere. Switched it back and SSH (and RDP and fileshare) connections are working now.

Thanks to all commenters; trying their troubleshooting steps and gathering their requested info is what led me to find this.